# Extension to shift 1/4" mount forward?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, screw-mount, camera-modification

I have a 3d printed attachment for my lenses which is heavy enough to make my small tripod not balance. I would like to shift the 1/4" threaded connection forward about 2 inches. Is there a product that does this? I can't seem to find one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called a cheese plate; like this one from SmallRig.

[image]

You would use a 1/4-20 screw through one of the 3/8 holes into the current socket on the body; and then use any of the 1/4-20 holes in the cheese plate to mount to.

Comment: They're not hard to make, if you've got a drill press.  That's why I bought a 1/4"-20 tap

Comment: @ChrisH, sure... but for this job the cheese plate shouldn't cost any more than a decent tap does.

Comment: True.  I had a free piece of aluminium the right size, a suitable drill, and  tap wrench.  I've since used the tap for a couple of other things, as I knew I would (including as a substitute for 1/4"-20 UNC, which is slightly different and occasionally seen in my work)

Comment: This is what I was imagining! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If by "forward" you mean away from the photographer and towards the subject, you could use a tripod mount ring, also called a tripod collar:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could either use a tripod collar around the lens, or a rail like a off-camera flash bracket rail or a cheap macro sled with a tripod mount.

Comment: Appreciate the alternative options. The flash bracket rail might be more utility.